# DirectoryMatch expression with env variables to detect certain subfolders

Tags: regex, apache

I currently have an .htaccess file in the site's `DocumentRoot` to control direct access to certain files.
Two other applications, each with its own .htaccess, are installed in subfolders (`\app1` and `\app2`) but are impacted by the propagation of the parent's rules.

My goal is to move the root's .htaccess to the main Apache config with a condition to exclude them from applying to `\app1` and `\app2` subfolders.

I managed to detect the subfolders with a `LocationMatch`

```
<LocationMatch "^(?!/(?:app1|APP1|app2|APP2))/[^/]+">   
    Header set X-TEST-LOCATION "ROOT-APP"
</LocationMatch>
```

What would be the equivalent condition for a `DirectoryMatch` directive? I have a custom DEF_ROOT variable defined and this doesn't seem to work

```
<DirectoryMatch "(?!${DEF_ROOT}/main-app/(?:app1|APP1|app2|APP2))/[^/]+">
    Header set X-TEST-LOCATION "ROOT-APP"
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Apache 2.4 running on Windows.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with

```
<DirectoryMatch "^(?i)${DEF_ROOT}/main-app(?!/\b(app1|app2|app3)\b)">
    Header set X-TEST-LOCATION "D-MAIN"
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: Try to explain your solution a bit better, don't just copy paste code.